# In order to soundproof external noise, do I need to build wall stud on concrete walls?

Tags: home-improvement

I assume this wood framing is the [wall stud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall_stud).

[image]

My room looks like as follow with concrete walls

[image]

In order to soundproof external noise into my room (red circle), do I need to build wall stud?

Comment: what are you soundproofing from? external noise? noise into that small room? Common sense practice is to fill that stud wall with insulation just in case.

Comment: What level of sound-proofing do you require? From what sort of external noise, at what sound level?

Comment: @EnergyNumbers Does level of sound-proofingmean STC rating?

Answer (score 1):

The way I have seen it is to use 2 X 6 on each end and floor and ceiling of the wall then build two separate walls  with 2 X 4.  Stagger the 2 X 4 in the walls so the only solid contact for sound conduction are the 2 X 6 ends. Fill the space ( now 5.5" instead of 3.5" ) with insulation. The result is little solid contact ( at the ends) for conduction and a thicker sound absorbing insulation. I was describing a partition wall , but essentially you could put the same thing against a concrete wall ; The important factor , you don't want 2 X 4 touching both wall surfaces as they would conduct sound.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In your solution, which part is close to the concrete wall, the stud or something else, if the latter, then what is that?

Comment: The 2 X 6 one the ends and floor touch both walls but the 2 X 4 do not.

Comment: With a concrete wall in behind, couldn't you just build a standard 2x4 stud wall and leave it ~2" off the concrete wall and fill the void with sound insulation?  save yourself the need of a couple of 2X6